# JMETER Write and Read from the same CSV file between threadgroups

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter, I have a thread group which creates order, I capature the relavant details of the order and write to a csv file.

I have another thread group which searches these orders, the data for which I am currently creating as part of the above thread group as a prerequsite for this step.

Rather I wanted to check if there is an option to write and read from the same csv file, just to avoid the data preparation ahead. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this? Any constraints forseen on running with multiple user writing and reading from the same file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- With 1 thread - yes.
- With > 1 thread - still yes, but it will be dangerous due to [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), writing into the same file by multiple threads will result in data corruption.

If you need to pass values between Thread Groups there are following options:

1. [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)
2. [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in 1st Thread Group and [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the 2nd Thread Group if you don't want or cannot use the plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Inter Thread Communication plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) to share data between thread groups.

> You can put a string value into a queue from one thread, and then get that value from another thread, even in another Thread Group. This allows you having separate Thread Groups with some synchronization and parameter passing between them. There may be any number of FIFOs and they differ by "queue name".

1. Use the Inter-thread communication Post-processor to write the order information
2. User the Inter-thread communication Pre-processor to read the order information from another thread group

Sample [Test Plan 1](https://github.com/pragmatictesters/Pragmatic-Learning-JMeter-Training/tree/master/test_plans/examples/plugins) [Test Plan 2](https://jmeter-plugins.org/editor/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=openurl&utm_campaign=examples#/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri and Janesh. Will try the options sugggested and see it works in my case.